# How to use parametric typing with structs that have many fields different types

Tags: julia, parametric-polymorphism, automatic-differentiation

I have a struct that has quite a few different fields. Initially, I can use parametric typing for all of the fields. For example:

```
struct MyStruct{TF, TI, TB} 
    a::TF
    b::TF
    c::Array{TF, 2}
    d::TI
    e::TI
    f::TB
end
```

Now I'm using algorithmic differentiation with my code (I'm currently using the package ForwardDiff.jl). That means some fields will become the type `Dual`, and from what I understand that requires that either all of my fields become type `Dual`, or I have to make a unique parametric type for each field that might have a `Dual` come through.

Am I missing something? I feel like there is a better way to do this. Do I need to write a constructor that promotes all of my fields to the same type? Do I just use a different parametric type for every field (sometimes my structs have like 20+ fields)? Wouldn't that compromise any performance boost I might get? Should I leave the fields without type, and just rely on `Any`? What is going to be the most performant?

Comment: The Julia ecosystem has many packages for performing AD. Can you be more specific about what package you are using that defined the `Dual` type?

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently using ForwardDiff. I plan to use ReverseDiff in the future, but I haven't done enough reading to really ask on that right now.

Comment: I am not sure what your exact use case is but one possible option for consideration could be trying union types such as `a::Union{Dual, TF}`

Comment: You know, I hadn't thought about that. I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: I'm writing code that will be used to analyze wind turbines. I will use that code inside of a gradient-based optimization, hence the reliance on algorithmic differentiation.

Comment: See [limitations of ForwardDiff.jl](https://juliadiff.org/ForwardDiff.jl/stable/user/limitations/), the last two points are relative to the question: 1) Numbers should be `<: Real`, 2) vectors should be `<: AbstractArray`. Current implementation of "MyStruct" seems OK for me to work with ForwardDiff.jl. P.S. `Matrix{T}` is a more readable alias for `Array{T,2}`.